# Boxing conversion from bool to generic interface<T>

Tags: c#, generics, casting, boxing

This is a simplified version of my code (I need only the clue to go on).

Suppose I have an interface:

```
public interface IParse <T>
{
    bool TryParse (string value, out T result);
}
```

and  this is a method of my `Class`:

```
public static T GetParsedValueOrDefault<T>(string val)  where T : IParse<T>
{
        T ret = default (T);
        ret.TryParse(val, out ret);
        return ret
}
```

I can not use this syntax:

```
Class.GetParsedValueOrDefault<bool>("False"); //Error
```

I get the error:

```
There is no boxing conversion from 'bool' to 'IParse<bool>'
```

How can I make this or any suggested similar approach to work?

P/S : Hey search gurus, please point me to the question which it is a duplicate of (tnx)

Comment: How is 'bool' ever going to be of type IParse<T> ?

Comment: @DaveBish: Well, since bool type has a TryParse method I want a working approach to make use of it.

Comment: Nope, Boolean struct should inherit your interface in order to work, which is never going to happen.

Comment: Tell us what you're trying to achieve. We'll help you.

Comment: Thanks friends, that is what I needed, a valuable set of hints by skilled experts in the field. Well I need some time to digest them. Please accept my +1 for now until then.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've rewritten my answer for a second time now that I realize why you thought your code would work. You're misunderstand the way generics/interfaces work if you think that the `int` type will automatically implement your `IParse<T>` interface. `int.Parse` (and `decimal.Parse` etc.) is static, so it can't implement interface members. This is the sort of thing that can be done with C++ templates, but not with C# (or Java) generics.

One solution is to use a delegate. It's not as elegant as what you're looking for, but it's not too bad:

```
public delegate bool Parser<T>(string s, out T result);

public static T GetParsedValueOrDefault<T>(string val, Parser<T> parser)
{
    T result;
    bool success = parser(val, out result);
    return success ? result : default(T);
}

// Examples
int result = GetParsedValueOrDefault<int>("123", int.TryParse);
Console.WriteLine(result); // "123"

decimal result = GetParsedValueOrDefault<decimal>("123.456", decimal.TryParse);
Console.WriteLine(result); // "123.456"

decimal result = GetParsedValueOrDefault<decimal>("invalid", decimal.TryParse);
Console.WriteLine(result); // "0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is: Where does it get an appropriate implementation of `IParse<T>` from? `IParse<T>` is an interface and you cannot instantiate an interface and there might potentially be several classes that implement `IParse<bool>`.

I suggest you to use a factory approach:

```
public static class Parse
{
    public static IParse<T> Create<T>()
    {
        ...
        return ...;
    }
}
```

And then your method would do this:

```
public static T GetParsedValueOrDefault<T>(string val)
{
    IParse<T> parser = Parse.Create<T>();
    T ret;
    if (parser.TryParse(val, out ret)) {
        return ret;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
public static bool GetParsedValueOrDefault<T>(string val, out T result)  where T : IParse<T>
{
    result = default(T);
    result.TryParse(val, out result);
    return result
}
```

but is a little strange.

Maybe you mean:

```
public static T GetParsedValueOrDefault<T>(string val)  where T : IParse<T>
{
    var result = default(T);
    result.TryParse(val, out result);
    return result
}
```